# No Bluetooth on CM12.1

Tags: cyanogenmod, bluetooth, samsung-galaxy-core-prime

I recently updated my phone (using a custom ROM), and it appears to be that my phone now doesn't have bluetooth.
Well, it do have a bluetooth radio, and that `Bluetooth.apk` on `/system/app`, but when I turn the bluetooth on, it doesn't do anything; I mean, it just immediately turn itself off everytime I turn it on.

My phone is Samsung Galaxy Core Prime SM-G360HU, running Android 5.1 Lollipop  with CM 12 / 12.1 (I can't remember; I'll update this one ...) and TWRP Recovery installed.  It is, of course, rooted.

Upon [Googling](http://www.google.com/search?q=No+Bluetooth+on+CM12+-+Samsung+Galaxy+Core+Prime&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8), it only suggests things about Bluetooth Audio (which I am not looking for ...), and how to fix them.

I've done a bit research, and found out that newer versions of CyanogenMod ROMs come with an unfixable bluetooth.

Should I install a different type of ROM (such as Resurrection Remix), or should I go installing the stock ROM?

***Please HELP!***

---

Update *(1)* :

The ROM that my phone is using is CM12.1

---

#### UPDATE ***(2)*** :

So, the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzWikRa31-8qNUNkSGlEOHlsOFE/view) *(outdated)* for the quick patches is now dead.  Luckily, I still have the file.

Here is the updated download [link](https://www.mediafire.com/?a941mthuvs4vdz3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a known problem when using

### [[ROM][5.1.1][SM-G360H/HU] CyanogenMod 12.1 for Samsung Galaxy Core Prime](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-core-prime/development/rom-cyanogenmod-12-1-samsung-galaxy-t3405669)

The original developer >>***doesntexits***<< already knew this and provided a flashable zip file which seems to fix problems related to bluetooth.
[image: Known Problem to the developer]

**[This flashable zip file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzWikRa31-8qNUNkSGlEOHlsOFE/view)** has to be downloaded and installed through the recovery.

---

all this information can be obtained from the original post on XDA-Forums